# How to set default epic link in Jira using Groovy

Tags: groovy, jira

I need to set epic link using groovy if a condition is true. I'm using the following script:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;

def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getOSGiComponentInstanceOfType(IssueManager.class)
def epiclink = CustomFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_1000") 
issue.setCustomFieldValue(epiclink,"MAR-1518")
```

But im getting this error:

[image]

I tried this code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296902/how-to-set-epic-link-in-jira-using-groovy) but it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You just have a typo. In line

```
def epiclink = CustomFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_1000")
```

you are calling the `CustomFieldManager` class (inital is uppercase)

However, you need to call your variable `customFieldManager` which is from `ComponentAccessor.customFieldManager`

So, the above line should be:

```
def epiclink = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_1000")
```

Comment: I fixed the type. 
However, now it marks the `import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager` as an error saying `unable to resolve class com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager`.
It seems that ComponentManager has been deprecated since JIRA 7.11 and I'm using a newer version.
If I mark this row as a comment it's saying the issue variable from the last row isn't declared.

Comment: There is no ComponentManager, just delete it :)

Comment: By the way, are you running this script on console or post function, validator, etc? If you are on a console (or any outside code) instead of just "issue", you should get a specific issue object. You can use `ComponentAccessor.issueManager.getIssueObject("<issueKey>")`